# Want to bind object within object in grid view. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource

My class structure is

```
public class Listings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    public ListingsImages[] images;
}

public class ListingsImages
{ 
    public string src { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string alt { get; set; }
    public string num { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind my grid view and i m binding as

```
List<Listings> p = getData(); //returns list of Listings
gv.DataSource = p;
gv.DataBind();
```

My grid view code is

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns=false>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("id") %>
                        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <%# Eval("title") %>
                        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <%# Eval(?????)%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

One Listings object containts 10 images ! Now the problem is I want to display 6th pic of all Listings object then ??
I have tried

```
 <%# Eval("images[5].src")%>
```

But it gives me error ! Kindly answer me what should be solution ? ( *Just only with one gridview and one datasource*)

Comment: @PranayRana I have not tried this 'Cz I found another solution so I choose that one btw thanks for answer ! I will use in future !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by  making use of `RowDataBound()` event of grid to do that............

```
protected GridView_RowDataBound(object sender,
  GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
            //e.row.DataItem -- points to data / object which is going to be bind with the row 
     }
}
```

Comment: Brief Explaination please  or any link

Comment: I don't think this helps. The datasource itself is the Listings class, which is not a collection. It is the images property that is the collection and that is not what is bound as the datasource.

Comment: @Rob Levine - in the rowdatabound you can query as well as can access the dataitme easily acc to me in this event he can able to do d task he want